# ReactNative ListView inconsistent separator lines

Tags: react-native-listview, react-native

On Android 4.4, ListView separator lines are inconsistent in thickness, and some do not render. 
I can't see how this can be a code issue, this is how I render them:

```
     separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
      }
      ...
      <ListView
      renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) =>
        <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={styles.separator} />
      }
      .../>
```

Here is a screenshot of a View with this problem:

[image]

This issue does not happen on iOS or Android 6.

Anyone had this problem before?

**Update**

I did a test, this is not Android4 issue. It happens on all API version when running on Nexus One device (in android emulator)

Comment: Is this a scaling issue?  Does it happen on a real device? I've had this issue with the iOS simulator before.

Comment: This has been reported by a user (happens on device) and I have reproduced it on emulator..

Comment: I've gotten around the need to render a separate `separator` view buy setting the `bottomBorderWidth` of each row to 1px.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Issue is still there with bottomBorderWidth. It looks like the spacing between row elements is not consistent.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue on iOS and worked around it by adding a hairline margin, like so:

```js
<View
    style={{
      ...styles,
      borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
      margin: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    }}
>
    {// ...row content}
</View>
```

Comment: I fixed with the sames solution in my native-base ListItem component inside of FlatList, just added marginBottomWidth = borderBottomWidth, that was 1 / PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(1) in my case. In react-native=0.57.8, android.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the height:`hairlineWidth` in style

Comment: "StyleSheet.hairlineWidth" to be more specific.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the issue. Neither does setting borders on the items themselves.

Comment: Hi @Giannis did you find any solution?? I am also facing same issue, could you please help me if you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved changing the view height from a number to StyleSheet.hairlineWidth as some folks said before. Trying to be more visual/specific:

Before:

```
renderItemSeparator() {
    return (
        <View style={{ height: .2, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' }} />
    );
}
```

After:

```
renderItemSeparator() {
    return (
        <View style={{ height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' }} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no fix. It's RN "render-canvas-bug".
But I found hack solution.

```
<ListView
    style={Style.listView}
    dataSource={data}
    renderRow={(data) => this._renderRow(data)}
    />`
```

Style.listView: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    }, // or another backgroundColor you need

Then:

```
_renderRow(goods) {

    return (
        <View key={'goods_' + goods.id} style={Style.listView_item}>
            <TouchableOpacity or View or ...
                style={[Style.flex, Style.flexRow, Style.separatorRow, Style.u_paddingVerticalS, Style.u_middle]}
                onPress={() => this._xyz(goods)}>
                <View>
                    <AppFont>{goods.name}</AppFont>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity or View or ...>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Only important TouchableOpacity style is Style.separatorRow to render your separator. This style should be inside listView_item, where you can use another styles.

```
listView: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
listView_item: {
    paddingHorizontal: em(1.5),
},
flex: {
    flex: 1,
},
flexRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
separatorRow: {
    marginBottom: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: Colors.canvasColor,
},
```

You can use StyleSheet.hairlineWidth instead of 1 but it's not a must.

Comment: Where can I get the more info about RN "render-canvas-bug"?

Answer (score 1):

I reported it on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13959)

My workaround was to style the containing view and text like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      rowViewContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingRight: 15,
        paddingTop: 13,
        paddingBottom: 13,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#c9c9c9',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      rowText: {
        marginLeft: 15,
      },
    });
```

This is the ListView:

```
<ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
             renderRow={(data) => <View style={styles.rowViewContainer}>
               <Text style={styles.rowText}>
                 {data.bb_first_name}
               </Text>
             </View>}
          />
```

Looks nice:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have empty rows in your data source. You can style your separators to see it

[image: example]

To avoid this just filter your data.

Comment: No this was a rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when trying to render a Divider with a width of 0.5.

It rendered properly on devices with pixel ratio of 2 (e.g. iPhone SE 2nd gen.) but rendered random width on devices with pixel ratio of 3 (e.g. iPhone 12).

As suggested by other answers, using `Stylesheet.hairlineWidth` fixes the random width issue but the problem was that the width was thinner than 0.5 on devices with pixel ratio of 3.

So this fixed my problem:

```
import { PixelRatio, View } from 'react-native';
...

export const Divider = () => {
  const width = PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(0.5);
  ...

  return <View style={{ width }} ... />
}
```