# Inconsistent width of separator while displaying list items

Tags: react-native

Following is the code to display list items with separators

```
</View>
  <Text style={{padding: 10}}>List Item</Text>
  <View style={{height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth, backgroundColor: 'grey'}} />
</View>
```

(Kindly assume that I have repeated above piece of code multiple times to get the list view appearence)

there is some inconsistency in separators

[image]

this issue had already been posted in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012355/reactnative-listview-inconsistent-separator-lines) and in [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8655), but there hasn't been any permanent fix for this issue and it's been almost 2 years since these issue has been posted.

So, I just want to know that has anybody found permanent fix for this in recent times.

Comment: This happens only on android emulator or ios simulator. Not in device.

Comment: @csath, it's happening in real devices as well. Can we anything to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found that works usually well enough is to add a small margin to the divider.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  divider: {
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    marginVertical: 1,
  },
});

return <View style={styles.divider} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is a bug in React-Native for Android where React-Native renders a separator for the bottom of one FlatList item, and then a second separator for the top of the next FlatList item, when the FlatList should really only render one separator between each FlatList item. I figured this out when I added marginVertical: 1 to my ItemSeparatorComponent and noticed the two distinct separators in between each FlatList item. The fix I found was to set my ItemSeparatorComponent height to 2 pixels, and then set marginVertical to -1 pixel:

```
      <FlatList
        data={companyGrowthRankings}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => `${Math.random()}`}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: windowWidth, height: 2, marginVertical: -1, backgroundColor: lessBlack }}></View>}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old post. But I still faced this issue. I fixed it by setting the item from Flatlist to have the same `backgroundColor` with `contentContainerStyle`

```
  <FlatList
        ...
        contentContainerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            </View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                <Text style={{padding: 10}}>List Item</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this is an issue related to emulators and IOS simulator because of scaling. This is just a visual mispresentation. I don't think it would happen on a real device.

Try your code with a real device or if its possible try with no scaling with device emulators or simulators.

Comment: I am experiencing this with real devices as well. I ahve checked in Redmi and Samsung. BTW could you let me know what is 'try with no scaling with device emulators'?

Comment: @Kishore emulators try to fit to the screen of your computer so they scale down to fit.

Comment: Thank you, could you suggest something to prevent this behaviour in real devices?

Comment: @Kishore I have never seen it on a real device so I don't actually know how to prevent it.